# How to score goodness-of-fit for one observation, when distribution is known?

Tags: normal-distribution, goodness-of-fit, z-score

Lets say I have 2 different normal distributions N1, N2.

Then I make one observation X1.

I would like to know which distribution (N1 or N2) it fits better and what probability/score it makes for each distribution.

P.S. As I understand, I can estimate modulo of z score only. If score z =.1 for distribution N1 and z = .2 for N2, then it is more likely that the value is from N1. Right?

Comment: Since you know both distributions you can normalize  both distributions to N(0,1).  The z score closest to 0 is most probable. So it is more mlikely to come from N1. Your terminology is a bit foreign to me. By probability/score do you want the probability density at z=1 vs z=2.  The N(0,1) distribution has a higher density at 1. If you look at the probability in the right tail it is approximately 0.16 at z=1  and 0.025 at z=2.